# Fast way to compute the Voronoi diagram knowing the k-nearest neighbours

Tags: algorithm, diagram, nearest-neighbor, delaunay, voronoi

I know it is relatively easy to compute the sets of k-nearest neighbours from a Voronoi tessellations. What about the reverse problem?
I already have the set of k-nearest neighbours (in 3D) and I would like to compute the volumes and centres of the Voronoi cells. Intuitively, there should be an O(n) algorithm that does that, right?

Has anyone seen something like this implemented somewhere?

Thanks in advance

PS: I assume that no Voronoi cell has more than k edges (this prior knowledge on the location of the points is probably what makes it possible to compute the diagram in O(n), independently of the dimensionality).

PPS: I further assume that for a given point, the vertices of the Voronoi cell belong to the set of kNN (see comments below).

Comment: What if the voronoi cell has more than k edges?

Comment: @rrenaud: good point. I am in fact looking for an efficient algorithm that would construct the Voronoi cell if is possible to do so and return an exception if it is not (in which case I will generate an additional neighbour point and start again - this is part of an iterative adaptation scheme for numerical approximation of differential equations).

Comment: If you work in a plane, then there's a O(n log n) algorithm for building Voronoi diagrams, no need to deal with kNN.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that would be Fortune's algorithm, right? I would like the method to work in 3D, though. I don't know of any algorithm to get the Voronoi diagram in less than O(N^2) in that case, which is why I was thinking of using the KNN (which I already have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the VD as follows. A point P and one of its k nearest neighbors Q define a half-plane H(P,Q) equidistant to both P and Q, and a half-space H+(P,Q) with boundary H and containing P. Then the Voronoi cell of P is the intersection of the H+(P,Q) for all Q in the k nearest neighbors of P.
Building this intersection is very closely related to the Vertex Enumeration Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem

You need to have enough neighbors to be sure that the correct VD is constructed and I'm not sure that your assumptions guarantee that. The only sure thing is that the real Voronoi cell of a point P is included in the cell that the algorithm above constructs.

Comment: Thanks! That would be a perfect formulation of what the algorithm should do. I am still looking for an efficient implementation, though.

Answer (score 0):

While there should be an intuitive algorithm, I don't think that there actually is one. While I have no formal proof (and couldn't make one up that fast), consider the following argument:

Consider the case where the k-nearest neighbouring points K of a point P are all to one side of P, i.e. there is a plane through P such that all points in K are on one side of the plane. The boundary of the Voronoi cell of P can then not be computed, in any way, from the points in K. This argument holds for any k, and I can't see any way how an algorithm could detect the presence of any point on the other side of P by nearest-neighbour analysis. Therefore, I argue that the Voronoi diagram contains more information than the k-nearest neighbours statistic and therefore the transformation from Voronoi to kNN is an irreversible reduction.

On the other hand, [Hugo Ledoux has developed](http://www.gdmc.nl/ledoux/pdfs/_07isvd.pdf) a n log n average case algorithm for Voronoization, you might consider that solution.

Edit: My argument is probably still too complex. Simple thought about kNN: Consider a cluster of k points that are the kNN to each other. The kNN subgraph for these points is disconnected from all other points, making the construction of a Voronoi diagram impossible. Or, in other terms, the Voronoi diagram contains the k-nearest neighbours for *any* k, thus cannot be reconstructed from any finite k.

Comment: yes, I totally agree. The Voronoi diagram contains more information than the kNN and it cannot in principle be reconstructed from one particular kNN. However, I am only interested in the cases where the set of points is "nice" (i.e., the vertices of the Voronoi cells are amongst the kNN that we already have - for cases where this is not true, I want to catch this exception, add new points, and try again). Thanks a lot for the reference to Ledoux's work. It looks very good and I didn't know about it.

Comment: @calys: The construction of the Voronoi diagram for well-behaved kNN cells is trivial: Construct the perpendicular bisector of the line between each point and its neighbour and then compute the polygon bounded by these lines. I just don't think it is possible to efficiently detect where this scheme failed. It is cheap, however, to check that it failed (area of Voronoi cells == area of enclosing rectangle).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that sounds like what I want to do. I was hoping to find an efficient implementation of this somewhere, done by someone with better programming skills than me... As for checking that the scheme succeeded, I will impose that all the Voronoi verticies are within a radius of R/2, where R is the distance of the furthest kNN. That's only a sufficient condition, but it's easy to impose and easy to check.

Comment: Have a look at the [geogram](http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html) library. It can compute a single Voronoi cells, and does it exactly.